# Compare each element in list of lists with a column in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to compare each element in a list of lists with a dataframe column.
For example,

```py
groups_rids=[['AX1','AX2'],['AX6','AX5','AX17']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'rid': ['AX1','AX2','AX6','AX5','AX17'],
                   'pid': ['P2','P0','P3','P9','P13'],
                   })
```

Here `group_rids` is the list of lists. It has to be compared with `rid` in `df`.

Dataset:

| rid | pid |
| --- | --- |
| AX1 | P2 |
| AX2 | P0 |
| AX6 | P3 |
| AX5 | P9 |
| AX17 | P13 |

**My result should be:**

| groups_rids | pid |
| --- | --- |
| [AX1,AX2] | [P2,P0] |
| [AX6,AX5,AX17] | [P3,P9,P13] |

For each rid of a list in `groups_rids`, I want to search `df` for it and if present, append the corresponding `pid`
The dataset is large. So 3 nested `for` loops take forever to print result. Is there a way to get the desired result without 3 nested `for` loops if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dict:

```
d = df.set_index('rid').to_dict()['pid']
```

And use it to build the Dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(((x, [d[el] for el in x]) for x in groups_rids), columns=['groups_rid', 'pid'])
```

```
         groups_rid            pid
0        [AX1, AX2]       [P2, P0]
1  [AX6, AX5, AX17]  [P3, P9, P13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create group ids from list index of `groups_rids`

```py
ids = {v:i for i, lst in enumerate(groups_rids) for v in lst}

out = df.groupby(df['rid'].map(ids)).agg(list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(out)

                rid            pid
0        [AX1, AX2]       [P2, P0]
1  [AX6, AX5, AX17]  [P3, P9, P13]
```